# Epplus Hyper Link without Under-line

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink, epplus

I was trying to create a cell with a hyper-link as per below, but why is this hyper link not displaying under-line in Excel.

```
  public static void AddHyperLinkText(this ExcelRange range, string hyperLink, string displayText)
    {
        range.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(hyperLink);
        range.Value = displayText;
    }
```

Could you help me?

Best Regards,
Sue

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign a Hyperlink style to the cell.  You may need to create it in the workbook as EPPlus does not seem to have this built-in.  To create the style (requires `System.Drawing`) :

```
private static void AddHyperLinkStyle(ExcelWorkbook wb)
{
    if (!wb.Styles.NamedStyles.Any(x => x.Name == "Hyperlink"))
    {
        var s = wb.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("Hyperlink");
        s.Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
        s.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
    }
}
```

Then you can assign it like this:

```
range.Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(hyperLink, displayText);
range.Style = "Hyperlink";
```

Note that you can set the text and link in the same line.

Comment: Thank you:) this is exactly answer.

Comment: FYI you must now use `range.StyleName = "Hyperlink";` to use a named style.